# Efficient way to collapse each row of a matrix based on a column index for each row

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to reduce the number of columns in a matrix row-wise by performing an action depending on a column index specified for each row. Given the following example data:

```
M = magic(4);
col_ind = [1; 3; 2; 4];
```

I would like to make a three column matrix, such that the first column contains the row sum of each row up to the specified column index, the second column contains the value of `M` in that row, specified by the column index, and the last column contains the row sum of the rest of the entries in that row, that is, produce the matrix `M_out`:

```
M_out = nan(4,3);
for i = 1:4
    M_out(i, :) = [sum(M(i, 1:col_ind(i)-1), 2), ...
        M(i, col_ind(i)), sum(M(i, col_ind(i)+1:end), 2)];

end
```

such that:

```
>> M_out

M_out =

     0    16    18
    16    10     8
     9     7    18
    33     1     0
```

Comment: Check out `tril`, `diag`, `cumsum` and `bsxfun`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see how I might able to use cumsum across rows with linear indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Stewie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123762/efficient-way-to-collapse-each-row-of-a-matrix-based-on-a-column-index-for-each/40124341#comment67518908_40123762), I will do it here using [`tril`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html). The second column is straightforward using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). Then the third column becomes trivial:

```
T = tril(ones(size(M, 2)), -1);
M_out = zeros(size(M, 1), 3);
M_out(:, 1) = sum(T(col_ind,:) .* M, 2);
M_out(:, 2) = M(sub2ind(size(M), (1:size(M, 1)).', col_ind));
M_out(:, 3) = sum(M, 2) - sum(M_out, 2);
```

---

Or, a bit more efficient using [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
cs = cumsum(M, 2);
M_out = zeros(size(M, 1), 3);
M_out(:, 2) = M(sub2ind(size(M), (1:size(M, 1)).', col_ind));
M_out(:, 1) = cs(sub2ind(size(cs), (1:size(cs, 1)).', col_ind)) - M_out(:, 2);
M_out(:, 3) = cs(:, end) - sum(M_out, 2);
```

Comment: Nice, but `arrayfun` is a wolf in sheep's clothing... It's _always_ slower than explicit loops (but shorter and easier to write if that's the main goal). I think I prefer OP's code though, if it was split into sections that are easier to read (`M(1,:) = ...; M(2,:) = ...;`). I suggest you substitute `a b c` with `M_out(1,:) M_out(2,:) M_out(3,:)` though, but that's up to you,

Comment: Thank you, I actually knew that `arrayfun` is slow, but I didn't know it is slower than the loop...! Now I will try to change my code according to your comment on the question!

Comment: `arrayfun` is a glorified `for` loop with a lot of overhead.  The only use I ever have for `arrayfun` is that it can generate cell arrays.

Comment: Thanks, `tril` doesn't work for the general case though as the `col_ind` vector may not have good structure.

Comment: @Alex You are welcome. Both methods give me the same output in case of your updated `col_ind`. In what case `tril` doesn't work for you?

Comment: My apologies, it does work! Thanks! (I just don't understand the magic!)

Comment: Ah, I see, that's very clever to use `tril` and the `col_ind` to generate the appropriate masks!

Comment: Yes, I also felt excited when writing it!